# Count after ajax in react

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, promise

I make slider and that get bug - after first click to next slide that only fetch data and count items.length like 0. And after second click it slides. How to count items length (240 * (items.length - 4) * -1) after APIRequest. Seems need promise, but even if I found solution how then check if data already loaded and do not load again. Please help me to understand and find solution for that task..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

import Journal from './Journal';


export default class JournalsGroup extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
    left: 0,
    loaded: false
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    //if !this.props.data
     this.APIRequest(this.props.id);
   }

   slide = (dir) => {
     let { left, items, loaded } = this.state;

     if(!loaded){
      this.APIRequest(this.props.id, true);
      this.setState({loaded: true});
     }
     if(left < 0 && dir === 'left'){
       this.setState({left: left + 240});
     }
     //todo: count items only after ajax
     if (left < 240 * (items.length - 4) * -1 && dir === 'right'){
       this.setState({left: left - 240});
     }
   }

  APIRequest = (id, all) => {
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('X-User-Agent', '');

    const myInit = { method: 'GET',
                   headers: myHeaders
                 };
   let myRequest;
    if(this.props.magazine){
      myRequest = new Request(`magazines/${id}/issues?limit=4`,
                 myInit);
    }else {
      myRequest = new Request(`catalog/category/${id}/issues?limit=${this.props.main ? 8 : 4}`,
                 myInit);
     //todo: pagination
     if(all){
       myRequest = new Request(`catalog/category/${id}/issues`,
                  myInit);
     }
    }

    if(this.props.all){
      myRequest = new Request(`catalog/category/${id}/issues`,
                 myInit);
    }

    if(!!this.props.data){
      this.setState({items: this.props.data});
      } else {
        fetch(myRequest)
          .then(response => {
            return response.json();
           })
          .then(data => {
            this.setState({items: data.data});
            if(all){
              this.setState({loaded: true});
            }
          })
          .catch( console.log );
      }
  }

  render() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a callback to your `APIRequest`

**Example:**

```
APIRequest = (id, all, cb) => { 
    // ...
    fetch(myRequest)
          .then(response => {
            return response.json();
           })
          .then(data => {
            this.setState({items: data.data});
            if(all){
              this.setState({loaded: true});
            }
            if (cb) cb();
          })
          .catch( console.log );
}
```

---

```
this.APIRequest(this.props.id, true, () => {
    this.setState({loaded: true});
});
```

**UPDATE regards to @Kyon's comment**

```
APIRequest = (id, all) => { 
    // ...
    return fetch(myRequest)
}
```

---

```
this.APIRequest(this.props.id, true)
      .then(response => {
          return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
          this.setState({loaded: true});
      });
```

Comment: Why would you give the callback to the API Request function, when you easily can return the promise and let the upper (caller) function handle the promise. Otherwise, we would end in the callback hell, that we lived before Promises exists.

Comment: Thank you for your improvement. I updated my answer. Does it look better now?